# Error writing to file when saving matplotlib animation with a given codec

Tags: python, animation, video, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I've had trouble saving an mp4 animation created with matplotlib with a given codec. However I should mention beforehand that I could save the mp4 animation without specifying codecs and that seems to work fine, except that I am not able to insert this mp4 animation into powerpoint for a presentation. Powerpoint says it cannot read the file because it is missing 64bit codec.

When digging further I discovered that Windows media player which is used by power point for the animations, has already some video codecs installed.

So I thought of saving the initial matplotlib animation with one of these codecs, which is also compatible with ffmpeg. The command `ffmpeg -codecs` on terminal lists the supported codecs and I could spot the codecs common with ffmpeg and windows media player, ex: MSS1, MSS2

So I tried to save the animation with the argument `codec` set as follows.

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 158,interval=300, blit=True)
writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
anim.save('film_v5.mp4', codec='mss1')
```

Nevertheless it leads to an error, no matter what type of codec argument I put.

So I was wondering perhaps there was someone savvy, willing to help me troubleshoot this problem. Despite my attempts I could not find any solution in the stackoverflow forum.

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: FFmpeg only has decoders for these codecs. Run `ffmpeg -encoders` to get a list of codecs it can convert to.

Comment: You can also just try `-c:v mpeg4`

Comment: it is true that `ffmpeg -encoders` gives a list of codecs and it worked correctly when I insert `anim.save('film_v5.mp4', codec='mpeg4')` and produces the file. However I'm still not able to open this file via powerpoint. Any idea how to find a codec that is compatible with powerpoint ? Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Try `-c:v wmv1` and `-c:v wmv2`

Comment: You should add the error traceback to the question. Otherwise people are digging in the dark.

Comment: @Mulvya where should I add `-c:v wmv1` ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried to add it initially but they said there was something wrong with the embedding of the code. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, `wmv1` is the codec name, so `codec='wmv1'` or `wmv2`. You may want to save the output as wmv instead of mp4.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this and keep you posted.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Powerpoint didn't seem to like it either and I ended up installing the codecs and it worked. Thank you for your help again.